Is Matthew 24 verses 15 to 31 a proof of post-tribulation rapture?
90% of Christians believe in pre-tribulation rapture.
Nevertheless in Matthew 24 verses 15 to 31 we read:
when ye therefore shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken of by Daniel the prophet, stand in the holy place .......... let them which be in Judea flee into the mountains ......... for then shall be great tribulation such as was not since the beginning of the world to this time, no, nor ever shall be .......... immediately after the tribulation of those days ......... shall appear the sign of the Son of man in heaven .......... and he shall send his angels .......... and they shall gather together his elect from the four winds, from one end of heaven to the other...........
Is Matthew 24 verses 15 to 31 a proof of post-tribulation rapture because if the rapture happens before the great tribulation who will the angels gather from the four winds from one end of heaven to the other after the great tribulation?

Where's your 90% stat come from? I'd expect a majority of Christians to not have any specific rapture/tribulation timeline, that's really only for premillienials.

It's a down-vote from me until you supply some authoritative source for that statistic, you change "90% of" to "Some", or better yet, you change "Nevertheless in" to "In" and delete everything before that.

The idea of a pre-tribulation rapture was unknown to any Christian prior to the likes of MacArthur and Schofield coming up with it. This view is rejected by a lot of Christians and I have yet to hear a sermon in any church upholding it.

Proof When Dealing with Prophecy
When discussing eschatology, the question of “proof” is inherently complex. End-times theology requires synthesizing teaching from various parts of Scripture—prophetic, apocalyptic, and didactic—into a cohesive framework. Tying these elements into a precise timeline of future events makes definitive “proof” elusive, as interpretations often reflect broader theological perspectives.
Pre-Tribulational View of Matthew 24:15-31
From a pre-tribulation perspective, the "elect" or "saints being gathered" in Matthew 24:31 are often interpreted not as the Church, but as a distinct group of believers who come to faith during the tribulation—commonly referred to as tribulation saints. According to this view, these are individuals who recognize Christ as Messiah during the tribulation period, including both Jews and Gentiles, and endure through its challenges or are martyred for their faith.
This interpretation hinges on several key distinctions:

Tribulation Saints, Not the Church
Pre-tribulationists often interpret the "elect" in Matthew 24:31 as believers who come to faith during the tribulation, referred to as "tribulation saints." John MacArthur and other pre-trib scholars suggest that this group includes those who endure or are martyred during the tribulation, distinct from the Church, which they believe was raptured earlier based on passages like 1 Thessalonians 4:16-17. This aligns with the interpretation that the Church is already with Christ in heaven during this time, as supported by Revelation 19:14, where believers return with Him at the Second Coming. See here and here.

Covenantal Context
Many pre-trib scholars, including figures like Mark Hitchcock, argue that Matthew 24 is primarily focused on Israel, not the Church. References to Judea and the Sabbath (verses 16 and 20) are seen as evidence that the passage is tied to God's covenantal dealings with Israel. The "gathering" in verse 31 corresponds to promises of a faithful remnant being regathered (e.g., Isaiah 11:12, Ezekiel 37:21) at the end of the tribulation as part of Christ’s fulfillment of His covenant. See here and here.

Two-Stage Second Coming
Scholars like John Walvoord and John MacArthur articulate that the Second Coming occurs in two stages: the Rapture (Christ coming for His saints) and the visible return (Christ coming with His saints). The "gathering" in Matthew 24:31 happens post-tribulation and is distinct from the Church’s earlier rapture. This timeline harmonizes with their belief that the rapture is imminent and occurs without preceding signs, unlike the Second Coming, which follows numerous tribulation signs. See here and here.


Primary Problems with this View:

Israel vs the Church
A significant issue with the pre-tribulational view is the rigid distinction it draws between Israel and the Church—a distinction that Scripture does not support. While some suggest that the Church replaces Israel (Replacement Theology), the biblical narrative reveals something more profound: the Church is not a replacement but a fulfillment and continuation of Israel's role in God's redemptive plan.
From the beginning, God's promises pointed to the inclusion of all nations. God’s covenant with Abraham declared that “all families of the earth [shall] be blessed” through him (Genesis 12:3). This inclusivity is echoed throughout Scripture, as seen in Isaiah’s proclamation that “mine house shall be called an house of prayer for all people” (Isaiah 56:7). The inclusion of individuals like Ruth the Moabitess, Rahab of Jericho, and even the mixed multitude during the exodus (Exodus 12:38) demonstrates that non-Israelites have always been part of God’s redemptive plan. These examples illustrate God’s ongoing mission to unify all people under His covenantal blessings.
The New Testament confirms that this unity is fulfilled in Christ, with Gentiles being “grafted in” to the covenantal promises of Israel (Romans 11:17-24). Paul writes, “And if ye be Christ's, then are ye Abraham's seed, and heirs according to the promise” (Galatians 3:29). Moreover, Ephesians 2:14-16 emphasizes that Christ has broken down the dividing wall between Jew and Gentile, creating one new humanity. This unity is reinforced in 1 Peter 2:9-10, where Peter describes all believers as “a chosen generation, a royal priesthood, an holy nation, a peculiar people”—terms once exclusive to Israel.
Rather than separating Israel and the Church, Scripture portrays them as one unified people of God. The Church, consisting of both Jews and Gentiles, fulfills Israel's mission to bring God’s light to the nations (Isaiah 49:6). Thus, the notion that the Church is excluded from the tribulation while Israel endures it is inconsistent with the biblical picture of God's unified redemptive work. Instead, all believers—Jew and Gentile alike—are called to endure together as witnesses to God’s kingdom.

A Revival of Repentance?
Additionally, the pre-tribulation view essentially creates a significant revival of repentance during the tribulation period. In Revelation 6:9-11 and 7:13-14, we see an uncountable number of Christian martyrs who "come out of great tribulation". Given this truth of faithful martyrdom during tribulation, if prior to the tribulation all believers are removed, there would need to be a mass growth in repentant individuals to come to faith in Christ for this to be true.
However, this narrative creates tension with the broader biblical context, which consistently emphasizes humanity's spiritual decline as the end times approach. In Matthew 24:12, Jesus warns that “because iniquity shall abound, the love of many shall wax cold”, indicating that the world will grow increasingly resistant to repentance. Similarly, Paul writes in 2 Timothy 3:13, “evil men and seducers shall wax worse and worse, deceiving, and being deceived.” This description of growing spiritual darkness challenges the idea of a widespread revival.
To add to this, Revelation 9:20-21 highlights that despite the catastrophic judgments during the tribulation, many still refuse to repent. “And the rest of the men which were not killed by these plagues yet repented not of the works of their hands”. This verse suggests that rather than a mass revival, the tribulation will see the hardening of hearts and increased resistance to God’s call.


There is much more that could be said, but I hope this helps in some way. God bless.

Up-voted +1. A thoroughly excellent expose of the many fundamental discrepancies involved in enforcing the pre-tribulation theory (a novel theory, beginning in the mid 1800s) upon Christendom. This answer highlights how unscriptural it is and that it undermines the Gospel, negates many of Jesus' parables and plays right into the hands of an evil Entity which desires millenial dominion on earth before the Lord returns in reality. My email address is on my profile, if you are interested. Regards.

@NigelJ Thank you for such kind words. Over the past year or so, I’ve been deeply studying this topic, and it’s been both challenging and enlightening. Growing up, I was taught a particular view, but taking the time to thoroughly examine Scripture for myself has opened up a much broader and richer understanding. (It’s also brought back much of my passion for writing).

Thank you @Jacob McDougle . I am in the UK, in Worcesteshire. On my profile you may see a link to my website and my writing. May the Lord bless thee.

God will not save the elect from the tribulation through a rapture. There is a multitude of saints who will be martyred during that era and they are mentioned in the book of Revelation.
Revelation 7:14-17

And I said to him, “Sir, you know.” So he said to me, “These are the ones who come out of the great tribulation, and washed their robes and made them white in the blood of the Lamb. Therefore they are before the throne of God, and serve Him day and night in His temple.

This is a martyrdom because it says they come out of the great tribulation which implies they die as a result of persecution by some satanic force that will be in control at that time.
The only intervention by God is shortening it to make it survivable for the elect.
Mathew 24:22

“If those days had not been cut short, no one would survive, but for the sake of the elect those days will be shortened.

There will be a rapture or catching to the air of the saints but I do believe this is when Jesus returns with a cloud and gathers all the elect from the four corners of the earth, it will not happen until Jesus blows the trumpet with the voice of the arch-angel.
Why would God shorten the rapture to allow the elect to survive if he could just save all of them before it(the tribulation) started through a rapture?
